# How can I simplify this jQuery code?

Tags: jquery, simplify

I'm trying to make each div slightly more opaque than the others, one at a time. As you can see I simplified some of it already by making variables.

```
var f1 = $('#f1');
var f2 = $('#f2');
var f3 = $('#f3');
var f4 = $('#f4');

if(art==1){
f1.css('opacity',1);
f2.css('opacity',0.9);
f3.css('opacity',0.9);
f4.css('opacity',0.9);
}else if(art==2){
f1.css('opacity',0.9);
f2.css('opacity',1);
f3.css('opacity',0.9);
f4.css('opacity',0.9);
}else if(art==3){
f1.css('opacity',0.9);
f2.css('opacity',0.9);
f3.css('opacity',1);
f4.css('opacity',0.9);
}else if (art==4){
f1.css('opacity',0.9);
f2.css('opacity',0.9);
f3.css('opacity',0.9);
f4.css('opacity',1);
}
```

Comment: Why are you posting this right after you posted [this same type of question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387150/simplify-this-jquery-code/9387437#9387437)?  Learn from the previous answers and try something yourself on this code.  If you get stuck trying something yourself, ask a more specific question.  We aren't here to rewrite your code for you.  Voting to close as too localized.

Comment: Because you can't really do this with a for loop. and I just started working with jQuery yesterday.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#f1,#f2,#f3,#f4").css("opacity", 0.9);
$("#f" + art).css("opacity", 1);
```

or in 1 line you could do:

```
$("#f1,#f2,#f3,#f4").css("opacity", 0.9).filter("#f" + art).css("opacity", 1);
```

I highly doubt you would see the change in opacity for div corresponding to #f+art
but if you did there is a way you could fix it like this:

```
$("#f1,#f2,#f3,#f4").not("#f" + art).css("opacity", 0.9);
$("#f" + art).css("opacity", 1);
```

which is kind of weird to filter out one of the values we specified already but I think otherwise you would need to use extra logic to remove that value.

PS. This is a code smell (f+art)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
var f1 = $('#f1');
var f2 = $('#f2');
var f3 = $('#f3');
var f4 = $('#f4');

var fAll = $([f1, f2, f3, f4]);

fAll
   .css('opacity',0.9)
   .eq(art-1) // -1 because arrays are 0-based
   .css('opacity',1);
```

You should read a bit about how jQuery uses resultsets (*not just single elements*) and how to [traverse](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) and [manipulate](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) them

Answer (score 0):

This isn't much simplified, but a good structure.

```
var f1 = $("#f1"),
f2 = $("#f2"),
f3 = $("#f3"),
f4 = $("#f4");
art == 1 ? (f1.css("opacity", 1), f2.css("opacity", .9), f3.css("opacity", .9), f4.css("opacity", .9)) : art == 2 ? (f1.css("opacity", .9), f2.css("opacity", 1), f3.css("opacity", .9), f4.css("opacity", .9)) : art == 3 ? (f1.css("opacity", .9), f2.css("opacity", .9), f3.css("opacity", 1), f4.css("opacity", .9)) : art == 4 && (f1.css("opacity", .9), f2.css("opacity", .9), f3.css("opacity", .9), f4.css("opacity", 1))
```